# C++ atomic increment with memory ordering

Tags: c++, concurrency, atomic, memory-barriers

After I have read C++ concurrency in action Chapter 5, I tried to write some code to test my understanding of memory ordering:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>

std::atomic<int> one,two,three,sync;

void func(int i){
    while(i != sync.load(std::memory_order_acquire));
    auto on = one.load(std::memory_order_relaxed); ++on;
    auto tw = two.load(std::memory_order_relaxed); ++tw;
    auto th = three.load(std::memory_order_relaxed); ++th;
    std::cout << on << tw << th << std::endl;
    one.store(on,std::memory_order_relaxed);
    two.store(tw,std::memory_order_relaxed);
    three.store(th,std::memory_order_relaxed);
    int expected = i;
    while(!sync.compare_exchange_strong(expected,i+1,
            std::memory_order_acq_rel))
        expected = i;
}

int main(){
    std::vector<std::thread> t_vec;
    for(auto i = 0; i != 5; ++i)
        t_vec.push_back(std::thread(func,i));
    for(auto i = 0; i != 5; ++i)
        t_vec[i].join();
    std::cout << one << std::endl;
    std::cout << two << std::endl;
    std::cout << three << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

My question is: The book says memory_order_release and memory_order_acquire should be a pair to correctly read the right value.

So if the first line of func() is load sync within a loop with memory_order_acquire, it should break the pair and make an unpredictable error on synchronization.

However, as expected, it prints after being compiled on my x86 platform:

```
111
222
333
444
555
5
5
5
```

The result shows no problem. So I just wonder what happens within func() (though I wrote it by myself...)?

**Added**: According to the code on C++ concurrency in action page 141:

```
#include <atomic>
#include <thread>

std::vector<int> queue_code;
std::atomic<int> count;

void populate_queue(){
    unsigned const number_of_items = 20;
    queue_data.clear();
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < number_of_items; ++i)
        queue_data.push_back(i);
    count.store(number_of_items, std::memory_order_release);
}

void consume_queue_items(){
    while(true){
        int item_index;
        if((item_index=count.fetch_sub(1,memory_order_acquire))<=0){
            wait_for_more_items();
            continue;
        }
        process(queue_data[item_index-1]);
    }
}

int main(){
    std::thread a(populate_queue);
    std::thread b(consume_queue_items);
    std::thread c(consume_queue_items);
    a.join();
    b.join();
    c.join();
}
```

Thread b and thread c will work just fine, no matter who access count first. Because:

> Thankfully, the first fetch_sub() does participate in the **release** **sequence**, and so the store() synchronizes-with the second fetch_sub(). There's still no synchronizes-with relationship between the two consumer threads
>   There can be any number of links in the chain, but provided they're all read-modify-write operation such as fetch_sub(), the store() will still synchronize-with each one that's tagged memory_order_acquire.In this example, all the links are the same, and all are acquire operations, but they could be a mix of different operations with different memory_ordering semantics.

But I can't find related information about this, and How read-modify-write operation such as fetch_sub() participate in the release sequence? If I change it to load with memory_order_acquire, will store() still synchronizes-with load() in each independent thread?

Comment: Undefined behavior is undefined. Expected observed behavior is one of the possible things which can happen with undefined behavior.

Comment: @Jeff So test on other platform is needed? Like ARM? What if I don't have the proper test platform... How to implement correctly by the way

Comment: Actually I do not see any race condition with your code. The threads will be properly serialized because sync is always written with memory_order_acq_rel which synchronizes with the read with memory_order_acquire. What problem would you have expected? I do not understand the code you propose under "Added".

Comment: @PaulR OK I will give more detail about the "Added" part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code shows a basic spinlock mutex that lets each thread take the lock implicitly by recognizing its own value, rather than changing a state.

Memory ordering is correct and even stronger than it technically needs to be.
The `compare_exchange_strong` at the bottom is not necessary; a plain `store` with a release barrier would suffice:

```
sync.store(i+1, std::memory_order_release);
```

Reordering of the relaxed operations is possible but does not change the output of your program. There is no undefined behavior and the same output is guaranteed on all platforms.
In fact, `one`, `two` and `three` don't even have to be atomic because they are only accessed within your spinlock mutex and after all threads have joined.

> So if the first line of func() is load sync within a loop with memory_order_acquire, it should break the pair and make an unpredictable error on synchronization.

Acquire/release pairing is correct since the release barrier at the bottom (in thread X) pairs with the acquire barrier at the top (in thread Y).
That the first thread acquires with no previous release is fine since there is nothing to release yet.

About the '**Added**' part:

> How read-modify-write operation such as fetch_sub() participate in the release sequence?

This is what standard says in 1.10.1-5:

> A release sequence headed by a release operation A on an atomic object M is a maximal contiguous subsequence of side effects in the modification order of M, where the first operation is A, and every subsequent operation:
>
> - is performed by the same thread that performed A, or
> - is an atomic read-modify-write operation.

So, in order to release data to another processor, a load/acquire operation needs to observe the value that was stored by the release operation or a later value as long as it satisfies one of these requirements.
Apparently, read-modify-write operations have additional properties that prevent updates to the atomic variable from reaching other processors in a less-defined order.

> If I change it to load with memory_order_acquire, will store() still synchronizes-with load() in each independent thread?

If you change the read-modify-write to a separate load/acquire (that sees the updated value) and a store/release, it is still correct, but it is no longer part of the same release sequence;
you have created a separate release sequence.

Comment: So you mean that since the release barrier at the bottom (in thread X) pairs with the acquire barrier at the top (in thread Y), the acquire barrier at the bottom (in thread Y) will not break the pair of thread Y and Z. And with the pair establish a chain of five thread, the variables will show proper value in all threads? The code above is just for test purpose. I will give more detail about the "Added" part and thank you for your answer!

Comment: The acquire barrier at the bottom of your code has no purpose. At that point, you 'release' data to order it for the next thread that 'acquires' it. Each of your threads acquires data after the last one; the threads are run sequentially. Check the part in the book about the 'synchronizes-with' relationship. That has a more in-depth description of how this works.

Comment: So... what about the "Added" part?

Comment: I'll expand my answer tomorrow with some info on release sequences.. Next time, when you add this much to the original question, it's better to ask a new question.

Comment: So the fetch_sub() with acquire order is for performance and acq_rel order will also work well here?

Comment: `fetch_sub` with acq_rel is a stronger barrier than necessary. It is not wrong, but you don't need it..An acquire barrier is just fine.